# How to do not repeat the same text in JSDoc, like #define in C language

Tags: jsdoc

I have to repeat the same text many times when I define links.
For example:

a link is {@link Parameter/peso/tiesto/casero~parametro.html#.isReal}

 {@link Parameter/peso/tiesto/casero~parametro.html#country}


It should be convenient to declare something like #define at the beginning of the file:

    #define address "Parameter/peso/tiesto/casero~parametro.html"


Next, I can populate shorter links, like:

   {@link address#.iisReal}

   {@link address#country}

Comment: I've not seen this done. I also don't generate docs from my jsdocs. That said, JSDocs support markdown, so have you tried using markdown reference links? https://sourceforge.net/p/jsdoc/wiki/markdown_syntax/#md_ex_reflinks

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, I am using the Markdown notation that is described in the link you provided. But, I am repeating the same link many times in the same file, because that notation is valid only in the same block.

Comment: You could write your own pre-processor to do the substitutions before running jsDoc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. [Graham P. Heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167956/graham-p-heath)

Actually, I am using the Markdown notation that is described in the link you provided. But, I am repeating the same link many times in the same file.
For example:

```
    /**
     * Method to do something [XXX][1] object from a `lwParR` JSON string.
     *
     * [1]: module-ppp_kkk-XXX.html
     * 
     * @param {string} - [XXX][1] JSON string
     *
     * [1]: module-ppp_kkk-XXX.html
     * 
     * @returns {number} [XXX][1] object.
     *
     * [1]: module-ppp_kkk-XXX.html
     * 
     */
```

The `description`, first `@param` and second `@param` are different blocks, and the Markdown notation is valid ONLY for one block.

Comment: Interesting, sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but I just don't know that this is possible spanning blocks. What about a substitution step before generating the docs? That's probably a large add on, but it if it is to improve your docs quality, maybe it's worth it?